# Creating an item programatically won't start a SP Designer Workflow

Tags: workflow, powershell

I create an item in a list using Powershell.
The item is created with my account and not with System account.

When the item is updated, a workflow is launched.
When I update with my account the workflow is launched perfectly.

But when I use another account, the workflow is cancelled.

PS : The User account I used is an owner of the Site collection.

Answer (score 0):

Does Workflow Starts and then failed or it doesnt start at al?! If it start then it failed try to elevate workflow permission using impersonation stem. [Here](https://info.summit7systems.com/blog/app-step-or-impersonation-step-in-sharepoint-designer-2013) is an artical about elevationg permission. As a diagnosing step try to change the workflow to simpler one like send an email! But if it doesnt start at all I have no idea about it.